# After UPDATE trigger - NEW and OLD column alias

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger, audit, journaling

I have a table with corresponding AFTER UPDATE trigger for changes auditing (Oracle 11g). 
Table Test01 to be audited:

```
CREATE TABLE Test01 
(
    Name Varchar2(40),
    Surname Varchar2(40) 
);
```

and table History01 for auditing of changes

```
CREATE TABLE History01 
(
    Old_val Varchar2(40),
    New_val Varchar2(40), 
    Changed_col Varchar2(40)
);
```

It works fine when I use column names with :old and :new aliases, like:

```
create or replace TRIGGER trg_history01
  AFTER UPDATE ON Test01
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  if :new.Name != :old.Name or ( :old.Name is NULL and :new.Name is not NULL ) then
      INSERT INTO History01 VALUES (:old.Name, :new.Name, 'Name');
  if :new.Surname != :old.Surname or ( :old.Surname is NULL and :new.Surname is not NULL ) then
      INSERT INTO History01 VALUES (:old.Surname, :new.Surname, 'Surname');
end if  
  end if;
END;
```

Test01 could contain more columns and so I would like to iterate over all columns instead of to use column names. But I don't know how to do it, because folowing code does not work (cannot be compiled):

```
create or replace TRIGGER trg_history01
  AFTER UPDATE ON Test01
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  v_old varchar2(255);
  v_new varchar2(255);
  -- col_names contains all column names from table Test01
  CURSOR col_names 
  IS 
  ( SELECT column_name FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS 
    WHERE LOWER(table_name) = 'test01' );
BEGIN
  for col in col_names LOOP
    -- save column name into variable
    col_name := col.column_name; 
    -- to use it with OLD and NEW aliases, but followig two lines cause error "Bad bind variable"
    v_old := :OLD.col_name; 
    v_new := :NEW.col_name;
    if v_old != v_new or ( v_old is NULL and v_new is not NULL ) then
      INSERT INTO History01 VALUES ( v_old, v_new, col_name);
    end if;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Is there a way how to do it or I always have to use column names?

Comment: There is no way to solve this in PL/SQL, unless you use dynamic SQL to build and execute a dynamic function, which is a risky approach (Dynamic SQL  in Production is always risky.). The problem is the structure of your `history01` table. This is a very common anti-pattern. Storing old and new values in a row seems like a good idea but it isn't. There's the loss of datatype, there's the loss of structure, there's the additional overhead of inserting multiple rows of audit data for one changed row.

Comment: So, don't do this. Build a `history01` table which has the same projection as `test01` plus necessary metadata columns (transaction timestamp, dml action, etc). In the trigger insert a record of `:old` values (or `:new` values if that's your taste) into the audit table. The trigger can be generated from the data dictionary.

Comment: Also, don't build your own auditing system when Oracle bundle Flashback Data Archive,  their journalling capability, free with all editions since 11.2.0.4. [Find out more](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/flashback-data-archive-fda-enhancements-12cr1)